# Unable to display image in razor page that is in the domain home directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is an ASP.NET MVC application. I would like to display an image in a subdomain application on Godaddy. The image is located one folder up from the subdomain.

It is in an images folder in the domain root folder: `domain.com\images`

In the `cshtml` page no matter what I put for the source it looks in the folder `domain.com\subdomain\wwwroot\images`.

My html code looks like this:

```
string testpath = Url.Content("~/../images/8_Race_Logo.jpg");

<img src="@testpath" style="width:100px; height:auto;" alt="This is an image" />
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am able to upload the image files  into the folder from the subdomain so I don't think it is a permission issue.

Comment: All static content in an ASP.NET MVC app **must be** under the `wwwroot` folder in Visual Studio - that's the content that gets deployed to the website.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance since I am very new to web programming......Is there a way to specify the path in src using some other syntax to display from other domain folders? Isn't it possible to display an image from some other url on the web using src="http://....."? Is it possible to do something like that to point to another folder?

Comment: This Microsoft documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) addresses serving files outside of the web root folder.

Comment: With the help of marc and Dave I have resolved my issue. Thanks so much!!